# Mysqli throws trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this script which i am using to select a description from one table and inserting it into another table.

```
<?php
/**
Report Errors
*/
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("select subscriber_number,subscriber_category from subscriber_choices");

/*
500 Records Here
*/

$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$subscriber_number = $row['subscriber_number'];
$subscriber_category = $row['subscriber_category'];

$mysqli->query("select description from jobs_content where category = $subscriber_category order by rand() limit 1 ");

$text_message = $mysqli->query("select description from jobs_content where category = '$subscriber_category' order by rand() limit 1")->fetch_object()->description; 

$mysqli->query("insert into le_grand_out dest_msisdn,text_message,sender_name,service_id values ($subscriber_number,'$text_message',6789900,6388398399004)");

}

$result->close()

?>
```

When i run this script,i get an error on this line

```
$text_message = $mysqli->query("select description from jobs_content where category = '$subscriber_category' order by rand() limit 1")->fetch_object()->description;
```

which works when i for instance write

```
$text_message = $mysqli->query("select description from jobs_content where category = 'general' order by rand() limit 1")->fetch_object()->description;
```

Why am i getting this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/send_sms.php on line 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysqli_result::fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-object-returnvalues) returns `null` if no rows are returned.

So, if your query has no results your are running:

```
null->description
```

which is a property of non-object.

Comment: The problem was here `$mysqli->query("insert into le_grand_out dest_msisdn,text_message,sender_name,service_id values ($subscriber_number,'$text_message',6789900,6388398399004)");` which i changed to `$mysqli->query("insert into le_grand_out (dest_msisdn,text_message,sender_name,service_id) values ($subscriber_number,'$text_message',6789900,6388398399004)");`,i also modified my code to check if my vars were null.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you query is not returning anything try to check the query properly or use 
    if ($result)
    {
    //fetch Result here
    }